# Customize icons with css

Tags: html, css

In the following code snippet I have some html and css code. What I want to do is to get a perfect white circle outside logos. Is anyone able to help me? I tried to do it by adding border to logo and making its radius 50% but it didn't worked out. It didn't get me a perfect circle.

```css
h2 {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 2rem;
    text-align: center;
}

.my-skills {
     background-color: #353353;
}

.skill-div {
     display: inline-block;
     width: 23%;
     padding: 1%;
}

.skill-div i {
 font-size: 7rem;
 padding: 15%;
 border: 2px solid #fff;
 border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <!-- Fonts awesome link -->
     <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/4e3ab997f9.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<head>

<section class="my-skills">
          <h2>My skills</h2>

          <div class="icon-collection">
               <div class="skill-div">
                    <i class="fas fa-palette design-skill"></i>
                    <h4>Design</h4>
               </div>
               <div class="skill-div">
                    <i class="fab fa-html5 html-skill"></i>
                    <h4>HTML</h4>
               </div>
               <div class="skill-div">
                    <i class="fab fa-css3-alt css-skill"></i>
                    <h4>CSS</h4>
               </div>
               <div class="skill-div">
                    <i class="fab fa-js-square js-skill"></i>
                    <h4>JavaScript</h4>
               </div>
          </div>

     </section>
</html>
```

Comment: You should definitely left the not perfected circles in the code so people can see what went wrong. From what I can tell, to make that circle with border radius, you need to make sure the element is a square first, then your 50% border radius would be a circle instead of an oval

Comment: I have now edited the question. The problem is that the logos are not square so border around them is not square. I also tried to do it by wrapping logos inside a div but still didn't worked out for me.

Comment: Yes, the logo's sizes are different and not square, in my answer, I added a wrapper that is big enough to encompass the logos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, to make that circle with border radius, you need to make sure the element is a square first, then your 50% border radius would be a circle instead of an oval

I added a div wrapper to the logos, class `circle`. The width and height is just a number I came up with to contain the logos. You can make small adjustments to the vertically longer logos if you want to further center them vertically.

I made the css logo lower with margin top to better vertically center it. Ideally these logos would be in a sprite and should be the same size so these micro adjustment won't be needed.

Alternatively, I made the html logo less in height which also vertically centers it better due to my use of flex. But again, it is better for everyone if these micro adjustment can be avoided

```css
h2 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.my-skills {
  background-color: #353353;
}

.skill-div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 24%;
  padding: 1%;
}

.skill-div i {
  font-size: 3rem;
}

.circle {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.css-skill {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
.html-skill {
  height: 44px
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <!-- Fonts awesome link -->
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/4e3ab997f9.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <head>

    <section class="my-skills">
      <h2>My skills</h2>

      <div class="icon-collection">
        <div class="skill-div">
          <div class="circle"><i class="fas fa-palette design-skill"></i></div>
          <h4>Design</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="skill-div">
          <div class="circle"><i class="fab fa-html5 html-skill"></i></div>
          <h4>HTML</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="skill-div">
          <div class="circle"><i class="fab fa-css3-alt css-skill"></i></div>
          <h4>CSS</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="skill-div">
          <div class="circle"><i class="fab fa-js-square js-skill"></i></div>
          <h4>JavaScript</h4>
        </div>
      </div>

    </section>

</html>
```

Comment: So that means I can change the height and width of circle according to how big I want them to be. This was the point I was missing.

Comment: Yes you can change them to whatever fits your use

Answer (score 1):

```css
h2 {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 2rem;
    text-align: center;
}

.my-skills {
     background-color: #353353;
}

.skill-div {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 23%;
 padding: 1%;
}

.skill-div i {
     width:7rem;
     height:7rem;
     font-size: 5rem;
     display : flex;
     align-items: center;
     justify-content: center;
     border : 2px solid white;
     border-radius : 50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <!-- Fonts awesome link -->
     <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/4e3ab997f9.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<head>

<section class="my-skills">
          <h2>My skills</h2>

          <div class="icon-collection">
               <div class="skill-div">
                    <i class="fas fa-palette design-skill"></i>
                    <h4>Design</h4>
               </div>
               <div class="skill-div">
                    <i class="fab fa-html5 html-skill"></i>
                    <h4>HTML</h4>
               </div>
               <div class="skill-div">
                    <i class="fab fa-css3-alt css-skill"></i>
                    <h4>CSS</h4>
               </div>
               <div class="skill-div">
                    <i class="fab fa-js-square js-skill"></i>
                    <h4>JavaScript</h4>
               </div>
          </div>

     </section>
</html>
```

Let's see its fine now